# why does systemd cryptsetup try to remount the root partition already mounted?

Tags: linux, systemd, encryption, cryptsetup

I have /etc/crypttab as follows:

```
sda7_crypt UUID=<...> /dev/sda8:/keyfile luks,discard,keyscript=/lib/esi/tpm_key_pass
```

`sda7_crypt` is my root filesystem, so I use `update-initramfs` to decrypt it from early on (otherwise I could not continue boot).

Yet systemd automatically creates a `systemd-cryptsetup@sda7_crypt.service` unit, which depends upon a `dev-sda8:-keyfile.device`, which times out. This eventually fails, but it slows boot time down and creates error messages.

How do I indicate that this is already mounted by initram, and does not need to be mounted by systemd? I had thought about option `noauto` in crypttab, but was concerned it might prevent it from loading in ini tram?

UPDATE:

I tried `noauto`, it didn't work. Still mounts in initram, but also still tries on boot. crypttab now looks like:

```
sda7_crypt UUID=<...> /dev/sda8:/keyfile luks,discard,keyscript=/lib/esi/tpm_key_pass,noauto
```

What can I do to clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is 2 individual systemd issues, specifically how `systemd-cryptsetup-generator` works.

1. It doesn't recognize `keyscript=...` option, so it chokes on keys that are valid for `passdev` like `/dev/sda8:/keyfile`.
2. The systemd units automatically generated by `systemd-cryptsetup-generator` are not smart enough to recognize that the item already is mounted, and so tries to mount it again.

For more details, see this Debian bug report https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=618862

According to the bug report, you can stop it from generating the systemd units by passing kernel options `luks=no`, but that prevents *all* crypttab automatic mounting. This is fine if all you have is encrypted root, but if there are separate individual partitions, then they don't mount.

Answer (score 3):

According to debian's bug report masking the systemd unit is the best workaround for now.

```
systemctl mask systemd-cryptsetup@root_crypt.service
```

Thanx to Michel for this idea!